# In a homebrew campaign, how should I set CR for lesser and Boss monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew, campaign-development, cr-calculation

I am currently trying to make a campaign, and I am steadily homebrewing new monsters, all the way up to the boss at the end. I am aware of how CR works, but unsure how my monsters would shape up against actual players. I could, of course, test ALL of them against a bunch of characters, but obviously this would take much time away from making a campaign, and would almost be impractical given the range of characters that might be in a party.

Is there any algorithm that would allow me to determine their CRs more easily then testing them and more accurately than taking my best guess?

Comment: Do you own the DMG?

Comment: Can look it up, is there a specific page number that may help?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. You say you know how CR works but you don't know how to determine whether if the CR is suitable for your party? What resources are you using and have available? The DMG? Online resources? It would help to know what work *you've* already done to try to determine this as [we do expect a bit of research to be done prior to asking here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm new to online resources, so I'm using the DMG and other books here. I could not find anything related to CR in chapter 9, like you said, and what I am trying to do is find an *easier way* to determine CR and when I should level up my characters.

Comment: I am working on a homebrew campaign. I need to find a quick way to determine CR for several hombrew monsters, as I am not sure if I should increase or decrease their power to fit the party at that stage in the story. I have checked the DMG, but could not find specifics in chapters 9 &10.

Comment: @TheCentaur this site isn't for everyone *because* we're not a forum and we work differently to a forum. Idea-generation, brainstorming, and opinion-based question don't work well here because that's not what the site is built to handle. I feel this could be a workable question here but we need details on what specifically you're trying to achieve. As linksassin mentioned in the comments on the current answer, if chapter 9 of the DMG doesn't help you then we need *much* more information (edited into the question, not left as comments) about what you're looking for and how the DMG doesn't help.

Comment: I just realized the entire problem. The DMG I am using is outdated. Somehow, I did not realize that this copy I have is version 4e. Now I just feel stupid. My greatest apologies to all. I will delete this post as I have tagged it incorrectly. Again, sorry. I am not used to this online setup. This will be deleted in 10 minutes. Again, my apologies. Please completely disregard this question, and I apologize for my frustration.

Comment: @TheCentaur: Heh. I can see how a book from the wrong edition might cause confusion. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Chapter 9 of the DMG is your friend

This chapter covers the formulas and methods for determining the CR of modified and custom monsters.

You may have more questions after, but this is a good starting point.

### Use encounter builders to compare against your party

Calculators like the [Kobold Fight Club](https://kobold.club/fight/#/encounter-builder) use the encounter formulas from Chapter 3 of the  DMG to help guide you in difficulty evaluation.

Comment: I agree. Eating this chapter is the fastest way to acquire all knowledge about CR :)

Comment: @sdjz let's not get into how to ingest Information...

Comment: I have scanned this chapter and have not found anything that I need.

Comment: @TheCentaur Chapter 9 gives you the formulas on how to determine cr for a homebrew monster. Chapter 3 gives the formulas on balancing encounters via cr. If this answer doesn't answer your question than you need a significant rework of the question.

Comment: I apologize. I just realized that the DMG I am using is actually 4e. Again, sorry.